How do I display Job Title in my Next Auth app
How do I display Job Title and other user properties in my Next Auth app using Azure AD / Entra ID.
I am using next-auth v5 and Next.js V14 so I have an app directory and no pages directory.
This is my route.tsx (placed in [...nextauth]/):
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { options } from "./options";

export const {
    handlers: { GET, POST },
    auth,
    signIn,
    signOut,
  } = NextAuth(options);

this is my options.tsx:
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        AzureADProvider({
            clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
            tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
        }),
    ],
}

and this is my page.tsx:
import { auth, signOut } from "./api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"

function SignOut() {
  return (
    <form action={async () => {
      'use server';
      await signOut()
    }}>
      <button type="submit">Sign out</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default async function Home() {
  const session = await auth();
  return (
    <>
      {session?.user ? (
        <div>
          <p>Welcome {session.user.name}!</p>
          <div><SignOut /></div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>You are signed out!</p>
          <a href="/api/auth/signin"><button>Sign in</button></a>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

To display the job title make use of GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID?$select=jobTitle query

@Rukmini, but how do I use it in my code. And I only want currently logged in user's jobTitle

For logged in user job title make use of GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=jobTitle query

Does your code generate access token?

I think so but I am not sure, I created a new project and the only files I changed are the three files I mentioned in question.

Hi @Rukmini, I checked it, couldn't find anything related to displaying user's information. Besides they are using next v13. I don't have a pages directory

Check this https://github.com/dwarfered/ms-identity-nextjs-sample

The above Github exactly is what you need let me know if it works

Hi @Rukmini, I think it works, but they are not using next-auth library

My org is currently using next-auth, I have to check if I can avoid using it and follow this method instead. But you have contributed a lot of your time and efforts into this and I thank you very much for it.

I got the output successfully when I ran the code

I asked, they said we need to use next-auth

Sure will check with next-auth

Hi @rukmini, any luck?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This works
In your options.tsx add this:
providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account){
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token.accessToken) {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=jobTitle', {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token.accessToken}`,
            },
          });
          session.user.jobTitle = response.data.jobTitle;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching job title from Microsoft Graph API:', error);
        }
      }
      return session;
    },
  }

now you can use in your script as session.user.jobTitle

If you do not want to explicitly fetch info from server, you can simply use adapter which will automatically retrive info and expose them on session callback.
adapter stores user, account and session info on database.
Here is the sample implementation.

Include the Adapter
Import and configure the adapter :
You can use any supported adapters like FirestoreAdapter, DynamoDBAdapter, etc or create you own. As you have tagged azure you would need azure's storage but currently there is no official adapter so you can create your own or look for other's creation.
Here for example i will use Google's Firestore tp store user data.
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";


export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter: FirestoreAdapter(firestore),
    providers: [ AzureADProvider({...}) ],
};


Include jobTitle via session callback
export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter:...,
    providers:...,
    callbacks: {
        // include jobTitle with user info to consume on client and server side
        async session({ session, user }) {
            try {
                session.user.jobTitle = user.jobTitle ?? 'Default Job Title';
                return session;
            } catch (error) {
                session.user.jobTitle = 'Default Job Title';
                return session;
            }
        },
    },
    events: {
        //  add jobTitle field when a user entity is created
        async createUser({ user }) {
            try {
                if (user?.id) {
                   await db.collection('users').doc(user.id).update({
                     jobTitle: 'default title ' // or your logic to assign job title
                   })
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error in createUser event:", error);
            }
        }
    }
};


Use the Session Data in Your Client Component
Here's how to access jobTitle and other session details in a client-side component:
'use client';

import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export default function Home() {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession();

    if (status === 'loading') return <div><p>Loading...</p></div>;
    if (status === 'unauthenticated') return <div><p>Not logged in</p></div>;

    const name = session.user?.name;
    const jobTitle = session.user?.jobTitle;
    const profileImageUrl = session.user?.image;

    return (
        <>
            <p>Welcome, {name}!</p>
            <p>Job Title: {jobTitle}</p>
            <img src={profileImageUrl} alt={`${name}'s profile`} />
        </>
    );
}

Note



To update jobTitle for existing users, you can use the update function from useSession() hook or create a custom server-side endpoint to modify the user entity.
If you're not using an adapter for persistent data storage for users info, you can use jwt callback.

Ref: https://next-auth.js.org/adapters
